# How to reset all js objects in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a QML application which is based on `.qml` and `.js` files. These files can change during runtime of my app and in order to reflect this changes I call [clearComponentCache()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#clearComponentCache).

`clearComponentCache` successfully resets my `.qml` components but my js objects are **not** reset.

Here is a short draft of the problem:

```
import "JSTest.js" as JsTest

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(JsTest.getName()); //prints "oldName"
        JsTest.changeName("newName");
        console.log(JsTest.getName()); // prints "newName"
        MyManager.clearComponentCache();
        console.log(JsTest.getName()); //prints "newName"  since the object is not reseted. 
                                       //What I want is at this point is "oldName".
    }
}
```

JSTest.js:

```
var name = "oldName"
function changeName(newName) {
    name = newName;
}

function getName() {
    return name;
}
```

**My question is**: Is there any way to also reset all js objects to their inital state in one call ?

Comment: You can add some `clear()` function to your JSTest.js  which clears all the variables and so call it when you need.

Comment: @folibis yea that's obvious but not the solution I am looking for.